# SELECT WHERE CASE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I have the following table (MySQL):

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|    id    |product_id| store_id | stock_id | priority |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |   905    |    0     |     1    |    10    |
|    2     |   905    |    0     |     1    |    20    |
|    3     |   905    |    1     |     1    |     5    |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to filter by `store_id`, but if `store_id` doesn't exist, filter by `store_id = 0` instead e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE product_id = 905 AND store_id = 1
```

returns row 3 as expected;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE product_id = 905 AND store_id = 2
```

should return rows 1 and 2.

The following works where `store_id` can't be found:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND (CASE WHEN store_id = 2 THEN store_id = 2 ELSE store_id = 0 END)
```

However, the following returns all rows, rather than just row 3:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND (CASE WHEN store_id = 1 THEN store_id = 1 ELSE store_id = 0 END)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL 5

Comment: Have you tried with a nested `SELECT`. That might be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me the query below should be quite efficient and return desired results (assuming valid store_id is always positive; otherwise, another aggregate function should be used instead of `MAX` ).

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT MAX(store_id) as store_id 
   FROM table1 
   WHERE product_id =905 AND store_id IN (0,2)    
)b ON (b.store_id = a.store_id)
WHERE a.product_id = 905
```

For multiple products it can be changed to something like

```
   SELECT a.* 
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN 
    (
       SELECT product_id, MAX(store_id) as store_id 
       FROM table1 
       WHERE store_id IN (0,2)   
       GROUP BY product_id 
    )b ON (b.store_id = a.store_id and a.product_id = b.product_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

[@a1ex07 seems to have the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91187/877), but I'd like to give an explanation why your code was acting up

Your first query

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND (CASE WHEN store_id = 2 THEN store_id = 2 ELSE store_id = 0 END)
```

evaluates as

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND (CASE WHEN store_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

then evaluates as

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND 0
```

which brings back nothing

Your second query

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND (CASE WHEN store_id = 1 THEN store_id = 1 ELSE store_id = 0 END)
```

evaluates as

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND (CASE WHEN store_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

then evaluates as

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE product_id = 905
AND 1
```

which brings back everything